# Adding dropdown values dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown Markup like

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

From Server side I am getting values to be added as Comma separated like.

```
var dropdownMenuItems = "ADD,Substract,Multiply";
```

Now I want to add above values for which I have written like

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= dropdownMenuItems.length; i++)
 {
   $('.dropdown-menu a').add(dropdownMenuItems[i]);
 }
```

but I am getting error like `JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ,` in console.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the string in to an array using `split()`. Then you need to loop through it and create the `li` and `a` elements and `append()` them to the `ul`. Try this:

```js
var arr = "ADD,Substract,Multiply".split(',');
var html = ''
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  html += '<li><a href="#">' + arr[i] + '</a></li>';
}
$('.dropdown-menu').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
```

Note that you should use `<` not `<=` in the `for` loop, and `add()` is used to add elements to an existing jQuery object, not create content in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

try this one. it works

```
var dropdownMenuItems = "ADD,Substract,Multiply";
var list  = dropdownMenuItems.split(',');
$('.dropdown-menu').html('');
for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++)
 {
    $('.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="#">' + list[i] + '</a></li>');
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? `<=` in the loop will mean it iterates one time too many, and `add()` doesn't do what you are expecting it to.

Comment: Missed the `<=` ;)

Comment: Now its woking fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
var result = 'ADD,Substract,Multiply';

$('.myClass').html($.map(result.split(','), function(item) 
{
  return $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)[0].outerHTML
}).join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myClass">
</select>
```

Comment: Nice solution - but you're creating `option` elements in a select, whereas the OP is clearly creating `li` in a `ul`. Also note that `map()` is unsupported in <IE9 if you need legacy browser support